# htaccess rule to block login attempts with username "admin"?

Tags: .htaccess

I've removed the username "admin" from my installations but wp-login.php is still getting hammered.

Is there a way to use htaccess to block any requests from even getting to wp-login.php with if the login form is being submitted with username=admin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the 'admin' login name doesn't prevent anyone from trying to use it.

Interesting question about `.htaccess`. I've never tried it but from what I can gather [you can't rewrite based on `POST` data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1629648/1735890).

You can do it with [`iptables`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) rules if you have access to that level of the server, and, while I have great fun with `iptables`, it is a bit of a learning curve.

As far as preventing the login hammering, I have been using a plugin called [Limit Login Attempts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/limit-login-attempts/) on several sites and it works quite well. The plugin will track failed login attempts and save them in the database with an associated IP. It will ban the IP if a user configurable failed login limit is reached. The ban time is also user configurable. I'd recommend it, and I rarely recommend particular plugins.

Comment: Thank you @s_ha_dum - the linked answer is exactly what I was looking for: _You can't use POST data for mod_rewrite. This is because the POST data isn't in the HEADER of the http request, it's in the BODY._